# how create a continuous loop that calls a function using a random generated interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to execute a function every specified seconds, and it should loop forever. When the function is finished I want to start a new setTimeout using a random generated value between 2 and 5 (represents seconds).

Maybe badly explained but..

this is what I have so far.

```
function Start() {
    let count = $("section.mosaic").find("a.item").length;

    ChangePic();

    setTimeout(function () {
        let interval = CREATOR.PUB.Utility.randomInterval(2, 5);

        console.log(interval);

    }, 3000);

    function ChangePic() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Is ChangePic the function that is supposed to be called every few seconds?

Comment: @Hydrothermal yes correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the interval code into `ChangePic` so that it can call itself when it finishes.

```
function Start() {
    let count = $("section.mosaic").find("a.item").length;

    ChangePic();

    function ChangePic() {
        // do stuff here

        let interval = CREATOR.PUB.Utility.randomInterval(2, 5);
        setTimeout(ChangePic, interval * 1000);
    }
}
```

Note that this will call `ChangePic` once immediately when `Start` runs, and the random intervals will begin thereafter. If you need the initial execution to be on a delay as well, you could either copy the timeout code and run it instead of calling `ChangePic();`, or move it into a helper function that you call both inside `Start` and `ChangePic`.